# make/gmake: given a variable starting with multiple ../, create a variable with one less ../

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Given a variable, how can I create another variable with the leading repetitions of `../` that the first variable starts with, albeit with one less repetition?

For instance, given `../../../foo/bar`, how do I end up with `../../`?

I've tried a perl regexp like `perl -e '$a = "../../../foo/bar"; $a =~ /^\.\.\/((\.\.\/)+)/; print "$1\n"'` but can't figure out the magic incantation of quotes, backslashes, dollar signs, and so on needed to run it within `$(shell)`.

Further I suspect there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "variable"? A `make` variable with the required shortening of  one `../` can be constructed by: `$(patsubst ../%,%,$(ORIGINAL_PATH))`.

Comment: excellent, now how to get the foo/bar part off the end?  To be clear, starting with ../../../foo/bar I need to end up with ../../?

Comment: Can you be so kind to accept? Or did it fail for you?

Comment: @Vroomfondel thx.  As my complex make system design finalized, I ultimately didn't need this ability after all, so I didn't test your response but it looks great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove one `../` at the front:  `$(patsubst ../%,%,$(ORIGINAL_PATH))`

To isolate the first streak of `../` one could go as follows:

```
space := $(strip) $(strip)#
FIRST_STREAK := $(firstword $(subst $(space)../,../,$(subst ../,../$(space),$(ORIGINAL_PATH))))
```

Let's write this as a function:

```
space := $(strip) $(strip)#
UP_PATH = $(patsubst ../%,%,$(firstword $(subst $(space)../,../,$(subst ../,../$(space),$1))))
```

Test it:

```
ORIGINAL_PATH := ../../../foo/bar/../baz
$(info $(call UP_PATH,$(ORIGINAL_PATH)))
```

Output:

```
../../
```